Вывод своего столбца, который включает связанные данные из другой таблицы
Я новичок в SQL, поэтому просьба не судить строго. Пробовал нагуглить решение моего вопроса, но не смог найти нужного ответа.
Есть две таблицы authors и books
CREATE TABLE authors (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    name text
)
    
CREATE TABLE books (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    title text,
    author_id uuid REFERENCES authors(id)
)

Требуется получить данные в таком формате. Каким запросом это можно сделать?
{
    id: 'some book id',
    title: 'Romeo and Juliet'
    author_id: 'some author id',
    author: {
        id: 'some author id',
        name: 'William Shakespeare'
    }
}

Ближайший результат, который удавалось получить был таким
{
    id: 'some book id',
    title: 'Romeo and Juliet'
    author_id: 'some author id',
    id: 'some author id',
    name: 'William Shakespeare'
    author: {
        id: 'some author id',
        name: 'William Shakespeare'
    }
}

При использовании такого запроса
SELECT *, row_to_json(authors) AS author
FROM books
    JOIN authors ON books.author_id = authors.id


Вместо * укажите books.* и должно получится

@SwaD, да, это помогло, спасибо

SELECT books, row_to_json(authors) AS author
FROM books INNER JOIN authors ON books.author_id = authors.id;

SELECT * — это плохая практика, потому что она может привести к ряду проблем:

Медленная производительность: использование SELECT * может замедлить
выполнение запроса, так как он выбирает все столбцы из всех таблиц,
даже если нужны только некоторые столбцы.
Неконтролируемый результат: при использовании SELECT * невозможно
контролировать, какие столбцы будут выбраны, что может привести к
неожиданным результатам.
Уязвимость к атакам с использованием SQL-инъекций: использование
SELECT * делает приложение уязвимым к атакам с использованием
SQL-инъекций, так как злоумышленник может вставить вредоносный код в
запрос.
Трудности в обслуживании: при использовании SELECT * может быть
сложно поддерживать и обновлять код, так как изменения в структуре
базы данных могут повлиять на запросы.

Рекомендуется использовать явное указание столбцов в запросе, чтобы повысить производительность, контролировать результат и обеспечить безопасность приложения.
